# autolayout in IB versus in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, autolayout

I have a fairly complex set up going in the following way:

- the view controller and view are set up in IB. In IB I dragged a `UITableView`, hooked up the necessary stuff, and added 4 constraints to pin the top, bottom, left, right
- the table view has cells which use fairly complex auto layouts. i have a custom `UITableViewCell` which sets up constraints.

Everything works fine.

I then tried to replace the view set up in IB with a view declared in code, deleted the table view from IB, told IB to use my custom view. In my custom view, I created a single `UITableView` (setting the auto masking thing to false), and I added 4 constraints, pinning the top, bottom, left and right to the parent view.

However, when I do this, all my cells have auto layout errors "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints".

What I do not understand is - why given the same cells with the same auto layout code:

- it works when the `UITableView` is created in IB and constraints for the `UITableView` set in IB
- it gives constraint errors when the `UITableView` is created in code and constraints for the `UITableView` set in code.

This is my constraints for the `UITableView`:

```
override func updateConstraints()
{
    super.updateConstraints()

    if (self.didUpdateConstraints)
    {
        return
    }

    self.tableView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(
        ALEdge.Leading,
        withInset:kLabelHorizontalInsets)

    self.tableView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(
        ALEdge.Trailing,
        withInset:kLabelHorizontalInsets)

    self.tableView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(
        ALEdge.Top,
        withInset:kLabelHorizontalInsets)

    self.tableView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(
        ALEdge.Bottom,
        withInset:kLabelHorizontalInsets)

    self.didUpdateConstraints = true
}
```

`autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge` is a helper function that eventually constructs a `NSLayoutConstraint` and adds it to the "super view".

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: show your code that generates the autolayouts for the tableview in code

Comment: You can list the constraints on a view using the constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(_:) function. That would tell you if any constraints are left lying about.

Comment: @emrys57 where would be the best place to compare the constraints between IB and code?

Comment: I don't know, I've never tried it. But I do often read the constraints in the storyboard by looking at the XML in Xcode, storyboard - right click - open as - Source code.

Comment: I think I have an idea of the problem - the leading and trailing constraints are conflicting with the `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width` constraint that iOS is adding. But I cannot figure out why...